# Servicenow: Custom attachment widget in table not uploading documents onSubmit

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, attachment, servicenow

Our team is developing in ServiceNow's New York version and trying to incorporate attachments into a table widget.  We've created a custom attachment widget by copying what was done in this [post](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=f4301be5dbdcdbc01dcaf3231f9619ec).  Our code for that attachment widget is as follows:

```
<now-attachments-list template="sp_attachment_single_line" ></now-attachments-list>
<label style="float:left;font-weight:normal;cursor:pointer;">
  <sp-attachment-button></sp-attachment-button>
  <!--<span style="padding-left:4px;">${please fill them in excel and attach it to this request.}<br>Click <a>here</a> to add an attachment</span>-->
</label>
<sp-message-dialog name="delete_attachment"
                   title=""
                   message=""
                   ok=""
                   cancel=""
                   dialog-class="delete-dialog"/>
```

```js
function ($scope, $http, spUtil, nowAttachmentHandler, $rootScope, $sanitize, $window, $sce) {
  var c = this;
  c.quantity = 1;
  //$scope.data.sc_cat_item.description = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.data.sc_cat_item.description);
  $scope.m = $scope.data.msgs;
  $scope.submitButtonMsg = $scope.m.submitMsg;
  var ah = $scope.attachmentHandler = new nowAttachmentHandler(setAttachments, function() {});
  ah.setParams('sp_portal', $scope.data._attachmentGUID, 1024 * 1024 * 24);
  function setAttachments(attachments, action) {
  $scope.attachments = attachments;
  }
  $scope.attachmentHandler.getAttachmentList();
  $scope.confirmDeleteAttachment = function(attachment, $event) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("dialog.delete_attachment.show", {
          parms: {
              ok: function() {
                  $scope.attachmentHandler.deleteAttachment(attachment);
                  $rootScope.$broadcast("dialog.delete_attachment.close");
              },
              cancel: function() {
                  $rootScope.$broadcast("dialog.delete_attachment.close");
              },
              details: attachment.name
          }
      })
  }
}
```

```js
(function() {
    var m = data.msgs = {};
    m.submitMsg = gs.getMessage("Submit");
    m.submittedMsg = gs.getMessage("Submitted");
    m.createdMsg = gs.getMessage("Created");
    m.trackMsg = gs.getMessage("track using 'Requests' in the header or");
    m.clickMsg = gs.getMessage("click here to view");
    m.dialogTitle = gs.getMessage("Delete Attachment");
    m.dialogMessage = gs.getMessage("Are you sure?");
    m.dialogOK = gs.getMessage("OK");
    m.dialogCancel = gs.getMessage("Cancel");

    if (input)
        data.sys_id = input.sys_id;
    else
        data.sys_id = $sp.getParameter("sys_id") || $sp.getParameter('sl_sys_id');
    data._attachmentGUID = gs.generateGUID();
    // portal can specify a catalog home page
    data.sc_catalog_page = $sp.getDisplayValue("sc_catalog_page") || "sc_home";
    var validatedItem = new GlideappCatalogItem.get(data.sys_id);
    if (!validatedItem.canView())
        return;
})()
```

In our table widget, we embedded the above attachment widget in a column:

```
<td>
  <widget id="custom-attachments"></widget>
</td>
```

and the end result looks like this:

[image]

Right now, this allows us to "attach" documents by row, which is what we want.  However, once we press submit, nothing happens.  Once a user hits submit, we want a new case to be created for each row in the table and have corresponding attachments uploaded and attached to each new case.  Our code prior to adding in the attachment widget, created the cases, but now nothing gets created and nothing happens.  There is also no error in the console, so we're not sure what's happening exactly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It does not currently look like you have any server side code designated to handling the Submission. Is there additional code you have excluded that you could past?

If not, it looks as though you will need to write a handler that creates your records for you and another that uploads the attachments and then adds them to the created records.